# exporting output from c program to microsoft excel?

Tags: c

how to export the output of a c program to microsoft excel?

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is to probably produce a CSV, which is easy to import to Excel.

Comment: Far easier than any of the alternatives, like trying to invoke an Excel COM object from plain C <<shudder>>.

Comment: If your values don't contain commas in them, it's literally a comma-separated file, with a newline separating rows. Google for it, it's pretty simple.

Comment: @Sayli: put commas in between your values when you write them, and write them to a file. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Comment: Is there any function/code to implement this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf